# "I am acquiring a skill that only 1% has" Has or have?

Tags: verbs

What should I say?

"I am not making money, I am acquiring a skill that only 1% has"

"I am not making money, I am acquiring a skill that only 1% have"

So 1% people has/have this skill but I am getting confused what to use in this sentence because people is plural not singular word but in this case it says few people.

Comment: What does *few* have to do with it? You'd say: *Few people have this skill.* *No people have this skill.* *Many people have this skill. One percent of people have this skill.* The only place you'd use *has* is in *One person has this skill.*

Comment: @Suleman,  How will you calculate this 1% of people? If it's a group of 100 people and you say 1%, it's one person. Then you can say *one(person) in every 100 people has this skill*. If it's a group of 200 or more people, 1% is, at least, two people. Then you can say *1% of people have this skill*.

Comment: @mahmudkoya No, numeric agreement in language is not subject to arithmetical logic. Not one of these is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can understand the confusion because **percent** is singular, yet the *percent* doesn't really *have the skill*; There's an implication that it's modifying something. Because of this, it really depends on what the percent is modifying.  If it's modifying a singular noun, like "the workforce," you would still treat it as singular.  If it's modifying a plural noun, like "people," then you would treat it as plural.

I'd recommend specifying what the percent is of.  For instance, a singular entity:

> **Because** I am not making any money, I am acquiring a skill that only 1% **of the workforce has**.

or a plural entity:

> **Because** I am not making any money, I am acquiring a skill that only 1% **of people have**.

Another option is to use the word **percentile**, [which is defined here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/percentile).

> I am acquiring a skill that only the top **percentile has**.